# Understanding Multitouch in Android

Tags: android

I have been studying multitouch on android but i got couldn't understand some of the lines i found.i searched google but couldn't find that understandable resources. i am posting the code.

I understand most of the part except "first two lines of `onTouch` method", `if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && i != pointerIndex)` and `case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:`

Please explain them.
Thanks for your help~~

```
package --- ;

--imports--

@TargetApi(5)
public class MultiTouchTest extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
TextView textView;
float[] x = new float[10];
float[] y = new float[10];
boolean[] touched = new boolean[10];
int[] id = new int[10];

private void updateTextView() {
    builder.setLength(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        builder.append(touched[i]);
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(id[i]);
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(x[i]);
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(y[i]);
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    textView.setText(builder.toString());
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Touch and drag(multiple fingers supported!");
    textView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(textView);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        id[i] = -1; 
    }
    updateTextView();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK; 
    int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT; 
    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        if (i >= pointerCount) {
            touched[i] = false;
            id[i] = -1;
            continue;
        }

        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                && i != pointerIndex) { 

            continue;
        }
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(i);
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            touched[i] = true;
            id[i] = pointerId;
            x[i] = (int) event.getX(i);
            y[i] = (int) event.getY(i);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            touched[i] = false;
            id[i] = -1;
            x[i] = (int) event.getX(i);
            y[i] = (int) event.getY(i);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touched[i] = true;
            id[i] = pointerId;
            x[i] = (int) event.getX(i);
            y[i] = (int) event.getY(i);
            break;
        }

    }
    updateTextView();

    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    /*Extract the index of the pointer that touch the sensor
    Return the masked action being performed, without pointer index 
     information.
    May be any of the actions: ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP,
     ACTION_CANCEL, ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, or ACTION_POINTER_UP.
    And return the index associated with pointer actions.*/

 **int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;** 

     /* Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
     For ACTION_POINTER_DOWN or ACTION_POINTER_UP as returned by getActionMasked(),
     this returns the associated pointer index. The index may be used with 
getPointerId(int), getX(int), getY(int), getPressure(int), and getSize(int)
to get information about the pointer that has gone down or up.*/

**int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;**
```

For more details refer:
[Link 1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html)
[Link 2](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-3-understanding-touch-events/1775)

Comment: sorry but by "first two lines of onTouch method" i meant `int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK; 
    int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;`